# Why would this line be turning up a server ( 500 ) error?

Tags: php, isset, global

So... Hopefully this is simple.

I've got the following two lines; and after implementation, the first line - the 'isset' - is turning up a 500 error that I cannot pin down. Can anyone consider a reason why an isset against GLOBALS would do such?

I've commented out the first line and I do get an error on the second( which I might expect - thus the check ).

```
if( isset($GLOBALS['Debugger']))
    $GLOBALS['Debugger']->Debug(null,__METHOD__,"Recursively including at '$Path'.");
```

And similarly:

```
if( isset($GLOBALS['Logger']))
    $GLOBALS['Logger']->Debug(null,__METHOD__,"Recursively including at '$Path'.");
```

If I strip this check out, and do another check against a different GLOBAL, everything runs along smoothly... I just dropped the following line in for verification thereof...

```
if( !isset($GLOBALS['PHPRoot']))
```

And it makes it past this just fine.

I also just tried another approach to checking this - the 'array_key_exists' method - like so:

```
if( array_key_exists('Debugger',$GLOBALS))
```

And I get the same 500 error.

Any thoughts? It almost seems to me that it is throwing on Objects and not on Strings... Which makes possibly less sense...

Comment: What is the error you are getting in your error log?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not the *isset*... that makes no sense.

Comment: elaborate the second part and check error logs and tell us the result

Comment: You might all be as surprised as I am that the error log is actually not recording anything about this. If I comment out the isset, it will throw an error on the attempt to use the object, and will log the error in the PHP error log; but the failure on the earlier line is not producing anything in the log. And I'm not particularly blaming the isset - I'm just trying to figure out why it's presence is throwing a 500...

Comment: I can literally change the variable I am seeing - to '$GLOBALS['PHPRoot']' and get past this line; I also just tried performing the same operation on my global 'Logger' and it has turned up the same results. isset is throwing a 500 on objects, but not on a string?

Comment: And did someone seriously vote to close this? One baffling community sometimes...

Comment: It's hard to help you without an error message. Have you turned error logging on? Or could you reproduce this in a local environment with `display_errors=on` or simpler code that does not depend on your environment? If one just sees this question in review and doesn't really dive into it, someone might vote it as  *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to **reproduce** it in the question itself*.

Comment: Well I'd have to feed a couple of thousand lines into the editor to reproduce my exact execution environment - I've got a lot of pretty intense code behind all of this - but I have error reporting fully enabled before attachment to a custom error handler, which comes once it has been successfully instantiated; and neither the handler, nor the default enablement of reporting prior to said handler, nor the PHP error log are tracking any of this.

Comment: An interesting addition to all of this is the fact that after examining all of my globals - I end up with the objects being set - but their classes being ... not what I instantiated them as. Rather perplexing in itself.